# correlation calculation of masked array:

Tags: python, correlation, netcdf, masked-array

I have a sea surface temperature time series, and I want to calculate the correlation coefficients among the nodes in the tropics(30.0N to 30S). In the time series, the land information is present as masked data. I do not know how to handle masked data in correlation calculation.
Please help.
The data I used here is in this link
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SVKQ4uBDEZOuN7_ftd5tqpF9_NGKY3pZ/view?usp=sharing
[image]

I tried the following code, which did not work:

```
   temp5 = 'sst.day.mean.1983.nc'
   fh5 = Dataset(temp5, mode = 'r')
   sst5 = fh5.variables['sst'][:365]
   time = fh5.variables['time'][:]
   lat = fh5.variables['lat'][210:510][::35]
   lon = fh5.variables['lon'][::45]
   mar_05=[]
    for i in range(len(lat)):
            for j in range(len(lon)):
               for m in range(len(lat)):
                  for n in range(len(lon)): 
                   mar_05.append(np.corrcoef(sst5[59:90,i,j],sst5[59:90, m,n][0,1]))
     df = pd.DataFrame(data = mar_05)
```

Comment: Can you rewrite to explain what you mean by correlation coefficient of the nodes?

Comment: Yeah sorry - we can help you implement a method, but not conceive of one. You could try [earthscience.se] or [stats.se]

Comment: @RobertWilson, I want to calculate the (Pearson) correlation among all the nodes in the tropics. But few nodes are located on the land and masked in the time series, so the correlation list is NAN. How to handle it?

Comment: @MichaelDelgado, thanks for sharing the keywords; I searched but did not get a particular answer.  Can you please elaborate a bit more about the solution?

Comment: No I can’t, that’s what I’m saying. You’re asking for help designing or finding a novel statistical approach. You could ask on one of those two forums. Earth science might be a good bet. But your fundamental problem will still remain- you need to decide what you mean by correlation, because it doesn’t make sense to me in this context. You could average all northern and southern pixels first and then correlate them…

Comment: @Ruby I don't know what you mean by nodes, and it's wrong to assume people reading the question will. This is a coding website, so you need to ask questions purely in terms of code

Comment: @RobertWilson, the latitude, and longitude define a node. I ran a nested loop in the code over the longitude length inside the latitude length. Some coordinates (nodes) are on the land surface, which is masked, so how can we avoid those coordinates during (Pearson) correlation calculation? Or is there any way to calculate the correlation coefficient for the masked array?

Comment: @Ruby As I said, please rewrite the question so that it is totally clear what your programming question is. People should not have to read through your code to figure out what you are trying to do. I still don't understand what it is, so I can't imagine anyone else reading the question will

Comment: I have tried np.ma.corrcoeff instead of np.corrcoef, but still, the correlation list is NAN. Any plausible solution?